# Attach to existing screen session, but new window

Tags: bash, shell, gnu-screen

So I have a screen session running on one terminal/machine
I would like to write a script that would attach to that screen session on another machine, but to a new window in that screen.

Does anyone know how I can do this?  I feel like it might have somethig to do with `screen -x (session name) -p (window number)`...if i put "-" as the window number, it goes to a blank screen, but I want a fresh window.

EDIT: Not really looking for a solution anymore myself, a neat tool called "tmux" replaces screen and makes this all trivial.

Comment: If you start `screen(1)` on one machine, you can log out and retake the conection elsewhere. It even offers the possibility of opening seevral tty's and switch among them. Or do you mean something else?

Comment: @vonbrand The first machine must stay logged on

Comment: So what you really need is a way to share the screen (or at least some applications)?

Comment: @vonbrand I'm really asking for a way to share sessions.  I already know how to do this, but I can't -x into a session without joining an already existing window or going to the window selection page.

Comment: Do you want the screen session to be interactive and run a command in a new window? Or just start the script in the new screen window without an interactive session?

Comment: @uther interactive :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10599769/attach-to-screen-session-with-creating-a-new-screen-window

I was looking for the same thing

Comment: Hello and welcome to the Stack Exchange network :). Please try to sum up the information included in the link you provided so that readers know what to expect before they follow it.

Answer (score 6):

You can send send arbitrary screen commands to a session using the -X option.

For example, say you start one screen with the session name "test":

```
screen -S test
```

From another terminal (or over ssh), you can create a new window in the original screen session using the following command:

```
screen -S test -x -X screen
```

If you want to run something the in the new screen, you can do so by simply appending the command name to the end. For example:

```
screen -S test -x -X screen mutt
```

will run mutt in the new window. Be aware that this window will close immediately when the program exits, so won't be useful if you want to see the output of short-lived programs.

For more commands that can be sent using -X, search for "The following commands" in the screen manpage.

Comment: I just realized that I misread your question. The above solution will open a new window in the OLD screen. It sounds like you want to connect and then automatically open a window in the NEW screen (to avoid having to type C-a c immediately). I don't know how to do this, but it may be possible with -X.